# Is there a way to post to the user facebook wall without an appId?

Tags: ios, facebook

So I was wondering, is there a way to post to the user's Facebook wall without an appId using Facebook iOS SDK?

I would like a a modal window to be shown and the user would put the message, but it's just that We do not want the user to authorise any app to do that. Just post against his wall.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No. And if you do find a way to do this, then it wont take long for Facebook to block your app or patch against it.